# Max weight euclidean spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-tree

A maximum spanning tree can be found by running kruskal's algorithm(just changing the edges function and considering the max weight edges first). I am interested in finding the max weight euclidean spanning tree. Does there exist a better algorithm(better worst case running time) than kruskal's to find such a spanning tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Monma et al.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01840396) solve this in `O(n log h)` time and `O(n)` space, where `n` is the number of points and `h` is the size of the convex hull.

The algorithm (p.10 of the paper) is fairly simple so it should be accessible even without understanding the full proof.

[image: max spanning tree algorithm]

Comment: the document is locked by a sign in. Can you outline the algorithm or make it available...

Comment: Sure. I have attached a screenshot of the algorithm.

Comment: (This is for two dimensions only. I guess that's not a problem for the asker.)

Comment: probably asker wants to ask solution for http://www.codechef.com/APRIL13/problems/CHEFGAME (upto 5D). I would only answer this after 15th april